# Defining postive parameters for an indexed array in NonlinearModelFit

Tags: fitting

I'm fitting the model with this code:

```
par1 = Array[eta, 16];
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data[[All, {1, 2}]], 
Sum[(eta[i]/eta[i + 8])*Exp[-t/eta[i + 8]], {i, 1, 8}], par1, t]
```

And while it does find a decent fit, it uses 1 negative value at eta[3]. So I decided to make eta[3] positive by

```
NonlinearModelFit[
  data[[All, {1,2}]],
  {Sum[(eta[i]/eta[i + 8])*Exp[-t/eta[i + 8]], {i, 1, 8}], eta[3] > 0}, 
  par1, t]
```

By doing this the model takes negative values for all the other parameters. So I tried to call every eta[i] value to be higher than 0 by doing (Using j or i in the below code gave the same error)

```
NonlinearModelFit[
  data[[All, {1,2}]], 
  {Sum[(eta[i]/eta[i +8])*Exp[-t/eta[i + 8]], {i, 1, 8}], {eta[j] > 0, {j, 1, 16}}}, 
  par1, t]
```

Obtaining the error :

[image]

I would like your input on how to avoid this.

Just in case it is needed, here's the data: [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gt3zj2o3m1z9fgo/TACFpas_N_8_taua_0.05_za_inf_zd_9.5_lp_0.007247.csv?dl=0)

Comment: The workaround is shown in this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/159500/defining-postive-parameters-for-an-indexed-array-in-nonlinearmodelfit). For your problem I believe it becomes `NonlinearModelFit[
 data[[All, {1, 2}]], {Sum[(eta[i]/eta[i + 8])*Exp[-t/eta[i + 8]], {i,
     1, 8}], Sequence @@ Table[eta[j] > 0, {j, 1, 16}]}, par1, t]`.

Comment: Well, that worked! Thank you! (By the way, the answer you linked is this same problem)